# Analog for iOS NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore in Android?

Tags: android, ios, google-drive-api, synchronization, icloud

iOS provides a handy [`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestoredidchangeexternallynotification?language=objc) for synching user data via iCloud. It gives simple interface to write and read key-value data to iCloud. It doesn't require any special user authentication or permission on application start. Also, the system will automatically generate events in case of cloud data changed by application running on another device (of the same user). The usage is very simple: for example, `setData:forKey:` method will store your data same way as you do in dictionary, and another device will receive notification (it just needs to subscribe to `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification`)

I was looking for similar functionality to be used by Android app but the only solution I found is Google drive API. However, this seems very heavy: 1) it requires oauth2 authentication and user receives consent screen and request to choose account (as well as receiving emails about full access the app will have to his/her google drive), 2) this works just as a file storage, without key-value approach and without notifications on data change.

Is there a good analog in Android world for what NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore does? If not, what is the best strategy (without using own back end) to achieve real-time app data synchronization between devices in a way that would not disturb user (by asking to choose accounts and provide permissions) and with (possibly) notifications on data change?

Comment: I'm also looking for an `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` equivalent in Android to allow device-to-device syncing and identity persistence across devices tied to the same Google account: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64302491/2611730. I'm surprised Apple of all companies makes this kind of persistence easier than Android. Did you ever figure this out?