# How to get Android to store app data in user's Google account so it is restored on-install on new devices

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-firestore, accountmanager, android-backup-service

We're implementing a [loginless system](https://www.coursicle.com/blog/loginless-a-new-standard-for-user-identification.php) on our web, iOS, and Android app that allows the user to have a persistent identity without requiring any sign-up/sign-in flows whatsoever.

A key part of loginless is relying on iOS and Android to permanently store our app's data in the user's iCloud / Google account so that the data is automatically restored for the user in each of the scenarios:

- (i) Quitting and re-opening the app (accomplished with `SharedPreferences` in Android, `UserDefaults` in iOS)
- (ii) Uninstalling and re-installing the app on the same device (accomplished with `key/value backup` in Android¹, `Keychain` + `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` in iOS)
- (iii) Setting up a new device based on a backup of an old device (accomplished with `key/value backup` in Android¹, `UserDefaults` + `Keychain` + `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` in iOS)
- (iv) Installing the app on a brand new device signed into the same iCloud / Google account that the user previously used the app with (accomplished with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` in iOS)

The only case we have remaining is figuring out how to accomplish (iv) for Android. Does [key/value backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup) in Android restore the data in this case, even when the brand new device wasn't set up from a backup of an older device?

We've discovered the existence of [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify#ForYou) during our research, but it seems like the data in Cloud Firestore is keyed on an device basis so it wouldn't accomplish (iv), and it seems like AccountManager requires asking permission from the user to ask for their accounts via `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS`, plus the whole design of loginless is intended not to ask the user for any personally identifiable information. Are we correct in these conclusions, or could Cloud Firestore be used to accomplish (iv)? Is there anything else we can use to accomplish (iv) in Android?

¹ We decided to use key/value backup instead of auto backup because the frequency of backups is greater than that of auto backups. See more information on the difference [in Android's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup#Choosing).

Answer (score 1):

Shared preferences should restore from the previous device if the [android:allowBackup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup) attribute is set to true. As far as I know this works if you have your phone backed up at Google (Drive).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the IV point, previous to 2018 you could use the now-depracted [Android Drive Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation), but currently you can use the [Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata) to enable an app to use the customer space in their drive to store application-specific data.

```
This folder is only accessible by your application 
and its contents are hidden from the user and from other Drive apps.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't handle our use case. The next sentence of that doc on the API v3 API reads: "The application data folder is deleted when a user uninstalls your app from their MyDrive. Users can also delete your app's data folder manually." Moreover, it also states that we have to ask for permissions "Before you can access the application data folder, you must request access to the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"

Comment: MyDrive != User device. Similar to iCloud where iPhone users can clear manually the content of an app.

Comment: Got it, so they'd have to go to their Google Drive and delete our folder, so that helps. That said, we'd still need to request access, which is a no-go for us (we want it to be transparent to the user).